# Table padding in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've noticed that Internet Explorer seems to ignore a table's padding. I've tested version 7, 8 and 9.

What is the best workaround? I prefer a workaround that's based purely on CSS than one that involves wrapping tables in `<div>`s or messing with tags in general.

Comment: have you tried putting the padding on the `<td>`. thats ultimately where the content is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
td
{
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

As seen on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCHdG/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this actually works as a fallback for flex box in ie9. And while the original question has nothing to do with CSS flex,and this is probably a repeat, it solved an issue for us, so I will mention it here and hope it helps others.
flex: `.selector { display: flex; }` and no flex fallback:
`.no-flexbox .selector { display: table-cell; padding : 25%; }`